# power series with integral coefficients is rational?

Tags: complex-analysis

there is a theorem of Borel which says a power series with integral coefficients  which is meromorphic in a disc with radius greater than 1 is a rational function can anybody give a hint about its proof or an English reference.

Comment: If $a_n r^n\to 0$, $r>1$ and every $a_n$ is an integer, then certainly $a_n$ is eventually zero.

Comment: Note: "meromorphic" allows poles.  So, for example, $1/(1-z)$ is meromorphic in the whole plane, and its Maclaurin series has integer coefficients, so (by Borel's theorem) we may conclude it is a rational function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the power series $\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n\,z^n$ with integer $c_n$. If $c_n\neq0,$ we have $|c_n|\ge1,$ and if there are infinitely many of those,  $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}\ge1,$ meaning the convergence radius is $\le1.$ This means only a finite number of coefficients can be different from zero, i.e. it is a polynomial.